# Visual Studio Community 2019 reference in UWP Core is Empty

Tags: c#, .net, reference, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to add `Windows.Gaming.Input` reference from windows universal core to my project in visual studio community 2019, but the reference under "Reference Manager >> universal windows >> core" in my visual studio is empty.

Other reference like "Reference Manager >> COM >> Type Libraries" is still there

[image: Reference Empty]

I'm already try to install the SDK, but the installer said my SDK feature is up to date.
I also try to download `Windows.Gaming.Input.dll` and load it via "Reference Manager >> Browse" but the result said `A reference to Windows.Gaming.Input.dll could not be added`

[image: The installer said my SDK up to date]

is there any solution for this?

Comment: Have you installed the UWP workload from the VS installer?

Comment: where is that option? i already re-download my installer, and run it but i cant find the option

Comment: ok, i found the option, i will try it, thanks

Comment: run VS 2019 installer and here select 18362 SDK and UWP workload